# how to iteratively subtract and compare values in java

Tags: java

there are n metric values like below

```
metric of feature clear 0.4054651081081644
metric of board various 0.6931471805599453
metric of design few 0.025975486403260736
metric of call end 0.13353139262452257
metric of bag other 0.1823215567939546
```

Now, the highest value has to be taken(board various). From highest value how subtract all the other values one by one iteratively and retrieve values that are above 0.02

Comment: You have tried something, show it.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Double> vals = <list of your values>

double max = Collections.max(vals);

vals.remove(max);
double result = vals.stream()
                    .filter(v -> v > .02)
                    .reduce(max, (v1, v2) -> v1 - v2);
```

Comment: Students should be prepared for the future! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code (Python, actually):

```
metrics = [0.4054651081081644, 0.6931471805599453, ... 0.1823215567939546]
mx = max(metrics)
for m in metrics:
    if m != mx and m > 0.02:
        mx = mx - m
```

The translation to Java is left as an exercise to the reader.

**Caution:** Comparing floating point numbers can be tricky.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, but you are welcome to fix such typos :)

Comment: Not during the time where you can edit your post without creating a new revision (I don't remember that "name" :D). It looks cleaner without that "edited by" part :).

Comment: But if all elements are qual to mx, you'll remove too much. (*"[...] subtract all the other values [...]"*)

Comment: @aioobe I fear the question is not clear enough to descide on this.

Comment: What do you mean. OP says *From highest value how subtract **all the other values***.

Comment: " and retrieve values that are above 0.02 " The "and" is vague.

Comment: How to iteratively subtract one value with the other and print the values greater than 0.1

Comment: @studybug, could you give an example? (please update your original question)